# Run a method before and after a called method in Java

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I'm trying to write a Java program such that after calling a *methodA()*, first a method named *methodBeforeA()* is called and then *methodA()* gets executed followed by another method being called named, *methodAfterA()*. This is very similar to what Junit does using Annotations (using the @Before, @Test, @After), so i think it should be possible using reflection but i don't have a very good clue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[AspectJ](http://thejavacodemonkey.blogspot.com/2007/08/using-aspectj-to-detect-violations-of.html) allows you to specify cutpoints before method entry and after method exit.

http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/starting-aspectj.html

> In AspectJ, pointcuts pick out certain join points in the program flow. For example, the pointcut
>
> ```
> call(void Point.setX(int))
> ```
>
> picks out each join point that is a call to a method that has the signature void `Point.setX(int)` — that is, `Point`'s `void setX` method with a single `int` parameter.

Comment: Honest question: does AspectJ advice still execute when the target method is called via Reflection?

Comment: @AlistairIsrael, http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/faq.php#q:reflectiveCalls suggests not always.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.. Came across this blogpost and it gives exactly what i was looking for.. http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-aop-aspectj-annotation-example/

Answer (score 3):

This would require modifying the method code to insert calls to the other methods. Java reflection lets you do a lot of things, but it doesn't let you dynamically modify method code.

What JUnit does is different. It identifies each method annotated `@Before`, `@Test`, and `@After`, then does something along the lines of:

```
for (Method t : testMethods) {
    for (Method b : beforeMethods)
        b.invoke();
    t.invoke();
    for (Method a : afterMethods)
        a.invoke();
}
```

You can certainly do something like this, to make sure you call the "before" and "after" methods after every time *you* call the method in question. But you can't force *all* callers to do the same.